# How to get sum by category in cshtml into one html table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

How to get the total for each category and at the end get the sum of all categories?

I tried cummulative total but it did not work.

Comment: Start here: http://linq101.nilzorblog.com/linq101-lambda.php  and search on SO for [linq group sum](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+linq+group+sum)

Comment: I’m looking for a solution to sum by category in cshtml page (razor).

Comment: Can you share your cshtml,we need to know the structure of the model which contains catrgories?

Comment: @abdulkareemamoora, you can implement razor page sum of all categories in following way.

Comment: I did this solution already. But, the requirement is to have the total for each category in one table.

Comment: Okay thanks for your reponse and glad to know that you already been resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.calculativeProductByCateories)
{
    foreach (var product in ProductBycategory)
    {   
        if (item.Category == product.Category)
        {
           <tr>
               <td>@product.Category</td>
               <td>@product.ProductName</td>
               <td>@product.Price
           </tr>
        }
    }

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>@item.PriceSumByEachCategory</td> 
    </tr>
}

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>@Model.GrandTotal</td>             
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the total for each category and at the end get the sum of
> all categories?

Well, though I got your requirement but this is not the correct way to ask question as someone might be misunderstand your issue. It would always be nice idea to share your scenario with reproducible code snippet. However, let's consider below scenario.

Model:

Assuming, I have below class: So will calculate price by each category and finally would calculate the total of all category prices.

```
public class ProductByCateory
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
       
    }
```

Class For Calculated Model:

```
public class CalculativeProductByCateory
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public double PriceSumByEachCategory { get; set; }
        public double TotalPriceOfAllCategory { get; set; } = 0;
    }
```

**Note:** Above class I would use while calculate final result derive from `ProductByCateory` class

**Linq Query For Calculating Each Category Sum and Total Sum:**

Let's consider I have below List of Product.

```
    List<ProductByCateory> productListByCategory = new List<ProductByCateory>();
    productListByCategory.Add(new ProductByCateory() { Category = "Cat-A", Price = 150.5, ProductName = "Product1" });
    productListByCategory.Add(new ProductByCateory() { Category = "Cat-A", Price = 250.00, ProductName = "Product1" });
    productListByCategory.Add(new ProductByCateory() { Category = "Cat-B", Price = 150.50, ProductName = "Product2" });
    productListByCategory.Add(new ProductByCateory() { Category = "Cat-B", Price = 150.50, ProductName = "Product2" });
    productListByCategory.Add(new ProductByCateory() { Category = "Cat-C", Price = 500, ProductName = "Product3" });
```

Thus, if I now calculate each category sum, I should get 401.5 for Cat-A and 301 for Cat-B therefore, 500 for Cat-C.

To meet above goal we can write our query as following:

```
List<CalculativeProductByCateory> sumListByCategory = productListByCategory
            .GroupBy(cat => cat.Category)
            .Select(sumByCat => new CalculativeProductByCateory
            {
                Category = sumByCat.First().Category,
                ProductName = sumByCat.First().ProductName,
                PriceSumByEachCategory = sumByCat.Sum(c => c.Price),
                TotalPriceOfAllCategory = productListByCategory.Sum(p => p.Price)
            }).ToList();
```

**Complete Sample:**

Asp.net core Razor Page `(cshtml.cs)`:

```
public class PriceSumByCategoryAndTotalOfALLCategoryModel : PageModel
{
    public List<CalculativeProductByCateory>  calculativeProductByCateories { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        List<ProductByCateory> productListByCategory = new List<ProductByCateory>();
        productListByCategory.Add(new ProductByCateory() { Category = "Cat-A", Price = 150.5, ProductName = "Product1" });
        productListByCategory.Add(new ProductByCateory() { Category = "Cat-A", Price = 250.00, ProductName = "Product1" });
        productListByCategory.Add(new ProductByCateory() { Category = "Cat-B", Price = 150.50, ProductName = "Product2" });
        productListByCategory.Add(new ProductByCateory() { Category = "Cat-B", Price = 150.50, ProductName = "Product2" });
        productListByCategory.Add(new ProductByCateory() { Category = "Cat-C", Price = 500, ProductName = "Product3" });

     

        List<CalculativeProductByCateory> sumListByCategory = productListByCategory
            .GroupBy(cat => cat.Category)
            .Select(sumByCat => new CalculativeProductByCateory
            {
                Category = sumByCat.First().Category,
                ProductName = sumByCat.First().ProductName,
                PriceSumByEachCategory = sumByCat.Sum(c => c.Price),
                TotalPriceOfAllCategory = productListByCategory.Sum(p => p.Price)
            }).ToList();
        calculativeProductByCateories = sumListByCategory;
    }
}
```

Asp.net core Razor Page (cshtml)::

```
@page
@model RazorPageDemoApp.Pages.PriceSumByCategoryAndTotalOfALLCategoryModel
@{
    double totalSum = 0;
}
<h2>Sum By Category and Total Sum</h2>
<table class="table table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category Name
            <th>Product Name
            <th>PriceSumByEachCategory
           
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     
        @foreach (var item in Model.calculativeProductByCateories)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Category</td>
                <td>@item.ProductName</td>
                <td>@item.PriceSumByEachCategory</td>
                <td hidden> @{
                        var total = @item.TotalPriceOfAllCategory;
                        totalSum = total;
                    }</td>
               
            </tr>
           
        }
       
    </tbody>
   
</table>
<h3>Total:<strong style="margin-left:640px">@totalSum</strong> </h3>
```

Razor Page Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If you are interested on [more details about Linq query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) you could [have a look here in official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)

Comment: Thank you. You did a great job. But, the requirement is to show total under each category in the first table.( only one html table).

Comment: If you do so `total under each category` would repeat because there would be more item for each category. Furthermore, please include enough code snippet for getting exact solution as you haven't shared anything.

Comment: Why to put code while it does not solve the problem? The question was very clear.  Maybe jquery can do the stuff.

Comment: Couple of reasons, its SO convention, another points is, if member shares their code and if someone solve the perticular issue using mebers posted code snippet, no longer any further confusion like I am not doing this way, this not I am looking for type of question wouldn't arise.

Comment: Mr. Farid, would you please tell me how to insert code into the web site like yours? Thanks.

Comment: Just add two loops (outer and inner loops). the outer loop reprsents the the total by category and the inner represent the category price. 
Inside the inner loop put a condition if the outer.category is equal the inner.category then add a tr with the details. Once the the inner loop finished add a tr for the outer.category. In this case you will have the total under each category. Amend your answer to mark it as correct.

Comment: @abdulkareemamoora You can insert your code snippet by updating your question and insert your code snippet by copying it then paste and format.